# DOMPDF How to get CSS Content :before rendered?

Tags: dompdf

In DOMPDF I have a problem, rendering content, which is set with CSS Attribute :before and content

I have a span:

```
 <span class="marker" position="1">
```

And the CSS

```
  .marker::before {
    content: "[" attr(position) "]";
```

But it does not appear in the DOMPDF Output.

What can I do ?

Comment: I'd say check the implementation of that library, ask them, raise an issue with them.

Comment: @arkascha DOMPDF says on their github page: 
"Check out the Demo and ask any question on StackOverflow or on the Google Groups"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current stable version of dompdf (v0.6.1) does not yet support the double colon syntax so you'll have to use the single colon syntax. Otherwise, so long as you are using 0.6.0 or newer this should work. Make sure your HTML/CSS is valid. The following sample seems to work fine:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
.marker:before { content: "[" attr(position) "]"; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <span class="marker" position="1"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was the double colon syntax (::before), with single colon it works like a charm.
BTW, I cannot find out my current version in the ReadMe or the Code, downloaded it some 2 years ago ..

So I will update now to version 0.7